# Angularjs issue $http.get not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, get, ionic-framework

I'm creating a mobile application using the framework ionic which is built on AngularJS.

I'm trying to load an image into my application from a JSON file but I cannot get it to load correctly.

Could anybody help me out?

Here's my HTML:

```
<ion-view view-title="Gallery" align-title="center" ng-controller="photoCtrl" ng-init="getImages()">
    <ion-content>
        <div class="col col-25" ng-repeat="image in images">
            <img ng-src="{{images}}" width="100%" />
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Here's my javascript:

```
.controller("photoCtrl", function($scope, $http) {     
    $scope.data = [];

    $scope.getImages = function() {
        $http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/30vuu')
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.data = data;
            })
            .error(function() {
                alert("Not working");
            });
    };
});
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting in `console`?

Comment: Also `ng-repeat="image in images"` to `ng-repeat="image in data"`

Comment: I'm not getting any errors in the console. I've changed image to data and still can't get it to work. Should it be images in data?

Comment: @smither123 @Icycool - It's `ng-repeat="image in data.images"` but only if the API return is fixed. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues here. First, your API call returns an object with a single property called images (not an array). Second, you're not accessing it in your HTML because that would be `{{ data.images }}` since your `$scope` member is called `data`.

So, the first thing you need to do is have the API return an array. If you do that, then use this HTML:

```
<ion-view view-title="Gallery" align-title="center" ng-controller="photoCtrl" ng-init="getImages()">
    <ion-content>
        <div class="col col-25" ng-repeat="image in data.images">
            <img ng-src="{{image}}" width="100%" />
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

And this JavaScript:

```
.controller("photoCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.getImages = function() {
        $http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/30vuu')
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.data = data;
            })
            .error(function() {
                alert("Not working");
            });
    };
});
```

---

If you only want your API to return one image then it's as simple as this for the HTML:

```
<ion-view view-title="Gallery" align-title="center" ng-controller="photoCtrl" ng-init="getImages()">
    <ion-content>
        <div class="col col-25">
            <img ng-src="{{ data.images }}" width="100%" />
            <!-- data.images because that's the name returned by the API call -->
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

The JavaScript doesn't need to change from what I have above;

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have created a codepen: http://codepen.io/beefman/pen/KpoNjz         I still cannot get it to work. I would like the api to return many images but this is just an example json.

Comment: @smither123 That's because your API call still returns an object with a property called images that is a string and not an array. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJxrob

Answer (score 1):

Please change

`<img ng-src="{{image}}" width="100%" />`

instead of

`ng-src="{{images}}"`

Comment: Change <img ng-src="{{images}}" width="100%" /> to <img ng-src="{{image}}" width="100%" />   ??

Comment: @smither123  you are looping images with ng-repeat and image is the value.